# (PHP) Problem with filename after downloading it

Tags: php

While writing a PHP-Script, im stuck at an issue i cant resolve.

The PHP-Script consist in letting a user download a .mp4 file. The download works without any issues but the file downloaded can not be played.

Heres the code:

```
<?php
  $filepath = "/www/servermedia/technounion.mp4";
  $filename = basename($filepath);

  header("Content-type: video/mp4");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=.$filename");
  readfile($filename);
  exit;
 ?>
```

After the .mp4 file gets downloaded, it cannot be played. 
It looks like this:[image]

The error message means that Windows Media Player cannot play back the file because probably the player doesnt support the codec. I already tried with VLC but it does not work either.

EDIT:

Comparing both file sizes, the downloaded file is only a couple bytes large instead of the 3,73 MB of the file on the server
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this has something to do with the php or script or not just the file itself. Does it allow you to open the actual file which hasn't been downloaded through your code?  Codecs usually have something to do with the creation of the audio file in the first place.

Comment: Have you looked into the file? Check the end of the file, sometimes error messages or warnings appear there, corrupting the file.

Comment: Yeah, the "original" file just plays back without any issues. I can open the downloaded file but it will not play back.

Comment: Do you check the size of the file? I think your script can't find the file and returns nothing as a file.

Comment: Can you check the content of the corrupted file? Are there any human-readable thing (e.g error message here?)

Comment: _“I can open the downloaded file but it will not play back”_ - then stop trying to open it using a media player, and use a text or hex editor, and see what it _actually_ contains.

Comment: The PHP doc suggests sending the "Content-Length" header, does that make any difference?

Comment: I did not check the file size, ill implement it now

Comment: Should you `readfile($filepath)` rather than `readfile($filename)` ?

Comment: I opened the file in Notepad++ and it says <b>Warning</b>:  readfile(technounion.mp4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\Users\infinitecodes\www\download.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />

Comment: But the funny things is that when i print out the variable $filename, it actually display the correct filename. So i don't know now where the issue is.

Comment: It has something to do with the path

Comment: UPDATE: If i move the .mp4 file to /ww/ it just works flawlessly, i have to figure out why it doesnt work when the file is in the /servermedia/ folder.

Comment: I posted an answer that should solve your issue... let's me know if you solved with my way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not well-formed, you miss to escape double-quotes by adding single-quotes as I done here, please test my answer.

```
<?php
  $filepath = "/www/servermedia/technounion.mp4";
  $filename = basename($filepath);
  header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  readfile($filename);
  exit;
?>
```

But I suggest a more complex way:

```
<?php
  $filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/www/servermedia/technounion.mp4";
  $filename = basename($filepath);
  header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf("%u", filesize($filepath)));
  set_time_limit(0);
  $fh = fopen($filepath, "rb");
  while (!feof($fh)) {
    echo fgets($fh);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
  }
  fclose($fh);
  exit;
?>
```

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is useful to get the full path from the server

`set_time_limit(0)` is useful to avoid any timeout during download

`fgets()` is useful for reading large files

`ob_flush()` and `flush()` assure that there is not other output in the buffer

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is the downloaded file the exact same filesize?

Does the content type exist in your webserver?
header("Content-Type: video/mp4"); Note capital 'T' for type.

This maybe worth testing with to see you can serve the file content inline:
http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2016/10/how-to-use-php-to-output-an-mp4-video/

Comment: Yes, the content type exists in my webserver

  header("**Content-type: video/mp4**");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
  filename=.$filename") but the filesize is not the same.